# How to Extract Header, Footer, and Data from SSRS report using the Webservice

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to write an integration with SSRS using the WebService where I take the existing reports that have headers and footers, and re-renders them using a custom theme from the website.

The idea being that the reports will look like they belong within the site, rather than having static formatting that's applied when they're created.

I can use the XML rendering method, but this only returns the raw data, and misses things like showing total fields.

Ideally, the XML version would include Header information, that I could generically parse to generate my own header.

The question, Is there an existing method that allows this? or a third party plugin that does it? is there another method to achieve this goal.

Comment: There may be a better solution then what I am providing here. The render method returns a byte[]. If you specify HTLM40 as the format you may be able to do some work with the raw result before it is displayed. I haven't worked with reports rendered in xml format.

Comment: Thats what I'm attempting at the moment, however there doesn't appear to be any consistency that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is, this is not possible unless you refactor your reports.